# FreeBSD could not boot any more as /dev/gpt/rootfs was no longer created, how to fix this?

Tags: freebsd, gpt

I have in my /etc/fstab

```
/dev/gpt/rootfs   /       ufs     rw      1       1
```

and gpart list shows a partition with the rootfs label:

```
3. Name: nvd0p3
   Mediasize: 16105245696 (15G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 1024
   Mode: r1w1e1
   efimedia: HD(3,GPT,1d7be3e1-14fe-11eb-9c6b-0cc47ad8b808,0x6b2,0x1dff946)
   rawuuid: 1d7be3e1-14fe-11eb-9c6b-0cc47ad8b808
   rawtype: 516e7cb6-6ecf-11d6-8ff8-00022d09712b
   label: rootfs
   length: 16105245696
   offset: 877568
   type: freebsd-ufs
   index: 3
   end: 31457271
   start: 1714
```

yet, the system wouldn't boot any more. I fixed it by changing the /etc/fstab to

```
/dev/nvd0p3   /       ufs     rw      1       1
```

and it would boot. This is from where I am looking at this disk now:

```
# ls /dev/gpt
bootfs
```

also here:

```
# ls -l /dev/gptid
total 0
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x46 Jun  6 17:28 1d7be3d4-14fe-11eb-9c6b-0cc47ad8b808
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x5a Jun  6 17:28 1d7be3dc-14fe-11eb-9c6b-0cc47ad8b808
```

these two are nvd0p1 and p2, but p3 is missing.

It seems as though this gpart label is damaged.

Then I went ahead and made another one. I just copied the entire disk and set up the gpt all from scratch.

And lo and behold, once again the rootfs partition label is not showing up as /dev/gpt/rootfs.

But strangely, when I am attaching this disk to another running system, the /dev/gpt/rootfs shows up. Just not when this disk is used as the boot disk, then exactly the /dev/gpt/rootfs is missing. Everything else is there.

This is really bad. I have no idea what it can be, and by now run out of patience to try and fail other options.

Upon request, here is the contents of /boot/loader.conf:

```
debug.trace_on_panic=1
debug.debugger_on_panic=0
kern.panic_reboot_wait_time=0
autoboot_delay="-1"
beastie_disable="YES"
hint.atkbd.0.disabled=1
hint.atkbdc.0.disabled=1
boot_multicons="YES"
hw.broken_txfifo="1"
if_ena_load="YES"
console="comconsole"
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to show the contents of `/boot/loader.conf`?

Comment: @JimL. yes sir, done.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines to your `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
kern.geom.label.disk_ident.enable=0
kern.geom.label.gptid.enable=0
kern.geom.label.gpt.enable=1
kern.geom.label.ufs.enable=1
```

Also, change your `/etc/fstab` line back to:

```
/dev/gpt/rootfs   /       ufs     rw      1       1
```

Give it a reboot, and comment below on your results.  For bonus points, add these further entries to `/boot/loader.conf`, and edit your post to include any interesting output produced:

```
kern.geom.debugflags=7
kern.geom.label.debug=2
```

Good reading can be found [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?geom(4)) but it may only be edifying rather than directly solve your particular case.